# Return a series of increasing order with highest length in an array (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have an array that contains:

```
num_array = [1,2,4,9,0,-1,6,7,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,3,7,0]
```

I want a result that checks for the array is in increasing order. say for the above 1 < 2 (true) then 2 < 4 (true) so far.. but when comes 9 < 0 (false) then break the array now start again 0 < -1 (false) so break the array -1 < 6 (true) 6 < 7 (true) 7 < 2 (false) so break the array. This will make several subarrays:

1. 1,2,4,9
2. 0
3. -1,6,7
4. 2,3,4,5,6,7
5. 4
6. 3,7
7. 0

Now I want to return the subarray with highest length. from the above `result = [2,3,4,5,6,7]` because there are 6 elements in series (ordered). Please help me code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
num_array = [1,2,4,9,0,-1,6,7,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,3,7,0]

# initialize a list of list with first item from num_array
result = [[num_array[0]]]

for i in num_array[1:]:  # start loop with second item
    if result[-1][-1] < i:  # append to last list
        result[-1].append(i)
    else:
        result.append([i])  # create a new list

# sort by length and get last item
print(sorted(result, key=lambda x: len(x))[-1])
```

Comment: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Comment: `result[-1][-1]` should return an integer. For example `[[1, 2, 3]][-1][-1]` should return `3`. What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry to bother you thats going great now. Thanks a lot for your help